# Add new subscription when previous complete

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have 3 *Disposaple* objects in my *CompositeDisposable*:

```
 CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

 disposables.add(
   interactor1
    .someMethod1()
    .subscribe(...some handling logic));

 disposables.add(
   interactor
    .someMethod2()
    .subscribe(...some handling logic));

 disposables.add(
   interactor
    .someMethod3()
    .subscribe(...some handling logic));
```

The first two methods return some data and transmit it to other methods. Third method must be called when first two completed. How can I do it?

Example methods signature:

```
 Single<List<String>> someMethod1();
 Single<List<Integer>> someMethod2();
 Single<String> someMethod3();
```

Comment: You probably want to combine the first two with the zip operator and call the third method in the subscription: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Answer (score 2):

An example is worth a thousand words:

```
public void SO() {
    Single.zip(someMethod1(),
            someMethod2(),
            Pair::create) // (1) create pair from results of someMethod1 and someMethod2
            .flatMap(methodsResultPair -> {
                // (2) handling logic of combined result
                // methodsResultPair.first is result of someMethod1
                // methodsResultPair.second is result of someMethod2
                return someMethod3();
            })
            .subscribe((resultOfMethod3, throwable) -> {
                // process resultOfMethod3
                // process error
            });
}

public Single<List<String>> someMethod1() {
    return Single.just(Collections.<String>emptyList())
            .doOnSuccess(objects -> { /* (3) handling logic of someMethod1 result */ });
}

public Single<List<Integer>> someMethod2() {
    return Single.just(Collections.<Integer>emptyList())
            .doOnSuccess(objects -> { /* (4) handling logic of someMethod2 result */ });
}

public Single<String> someMethod3() {
    return Single.just("");
}
```

With this you have one disposable instead of three, because all of them are now part of one reactive chain. `Single.just()` methods are used just for providing some dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

You would [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) the first 2 observables and then use [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) on the output of that. The zip function would project an item when both observables have produced a value, the combined object would then be passed to the flatmap which could then be passed to your third observable function.